# Is there a Powershell equivalent for aspnet_regiis key container import/creation?

Tags: powershell, rsa

I support a variety of older and newer ASP.NET-based applications, all of which rely on a standard key container for credential encryption. I am migrating much of the setup/configuration support for these apps to Powershell to the extent possible; however, I have not found an equivalent for the import of an xml-based RSA key:

aspnet_regiis -pi "ContainerName" "c:\SomePath\SomeKeyFile.xml"

There seem to be Powershell equivalents for nearly everything, but I have been unable to find one to accomplish this task. Does one exist?

Comment: Hello, I just googled what `aspnet_regiis` is and it seems to be a utility. Anyways, others have pointed to `Dism.exe` as an "*alternate*" solution. So, if that's the case, you can probably find what you're looking for here: [DISM to PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/use-dism-in-windows-powershell-s14?view=windows-11). Pardon me if that's incorrect.

Comment: DISM doesn't quite fill the bill. IT merely manages a Windows installation source and pulls out features for custom configurations. THe aspnet_regiis tool does all kinds of application-specific management, such as key registration, installation of older supported versions of ASP.NET, and performs configuration encryptions. I don't think DISM is designed to do any of that. Thanks for your interest.

Comment: @DavidW did you come up with an alternative to `aspnet_regiis`?

Comment: No, I didn't, unfortunately.